# Apply css class to a <div> generated by an <ng-template> within the <ngx-datatable-column>

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to apply `display: flex` property to the parent `<div>` of my `<span>`

but since the  is generated by the `ng-template` of the `ngx-datatable-column` I am unable to apply it in the html.

I tried adding a style property , tried using headerClass to the ng-template but it did not work.

This is how my html looks after its rendered.

[image]

I want to add a css class or a style property to the  pointed out in the image.

And this is my html before rendering

[image]

Can some one help me in adding a css class to the `<div>` pointed out in the image?

Comment: you can target this element from global style file

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmavi how can we do it? can you please give an example? If you mean targeting the element with the css class selector then I believe I cannot do that as that will apply my style to all the elements using that class. I only want to apply to this div alone

Answer (score 1):

Either use `style.scss`, which will apply the style to **all elements matching the selector**, or you can encapsulate it in your own component like so :

```css
ngx-datatable-column ::ng-deep .datatable-body-cell-label {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply CSS style to autogenerated class (datatable-body-cell-label) for apply style to div.

```
.datatable-body-cell-label {
  display: flex
}
```